# Covariant Fluid Flow approach

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology

I am doing Cosmological perturbation. Currently reading a paper by Bruni  et al. In that it is mentioned that they are using covariant fluid flow approach to cosmology. Can any body give me a rough idea on what Covariant fluid flow approach is.

Thanking in advance

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper so others have context to help you.

Comment: Sorry I am new to forums. So kindly pardon me, if my question is not clear. The link to the paper- http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1478

Comment: I suspect it's using the [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative) on the velocity, $u^\alpha_{\,\,;\beta}$. He lists two references next to the remark about the flow, have you checked them?